# Generic handlers (ashx) for images - very slow unless written to image first

Tags: asp.net, webforms, ashx

I've been rendering binary images from sql server for years, but usually only very small images.  Recently, I wanted to do this for larger images (500kb size).

I found that the old way I was doing it took a loooong time (45 seconds) to render the image. The new way was fast.  I've included both methods below.  Any ideas why the first is so slow?  I should mention I prefer the original way of rendering the images, because it's contenttype agnostic.

In both cases ImageData is stored as varbinary in sql server 2008.

**Slow Way**

```
        context.Response.Clear();
        context.Response.ContentType = user.ImageContentType;

        context.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Public);
        context.Response.Cache.SetMaxAge(new TimeSpan(0, 5, 0));

        context.Response.OutputStream.Write((byte[])user.ImageData, 0, user.ImageData.Length);
        context.Response.End();
```

**Fast Way**

```
            context.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Public);
            context.Response.Cache.SetMaxAge(new TimeSpan(0, 5, 0));

            MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream((byte[])prm.ImageData, false);
            System.Drawing.Image imgFromGB = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(memoryStream);
            imgFromGB.Save(context.Response.OutputStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);

            context.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Public);
            context.Response.Cache.SetMaxAge(new TimeSpan(0, 5, 0));
```

Comment: By the way - the exact image size is: 356081 and contenttype: image/jpeg